# Call constructor of dynamically generated object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have some code, that instantiates object, that looks like this

```
ObjectHandle instance = Activator.CreateInstance(assembly, cls);
return (T)instance.Unwrap();
```

Now, most of the time the type represented by `cls` has no constructors and is easily created.  But I have one class which has a constructor that takes a parameter.  Calling the above code on this gives the following error

```
Constructor on type 'X' not found
```

The parameter is an interface and I have configured Autofac to return a particular concrete instance of it.  My question is, what is the cleanist and niceist way of changing the code above to "find" this constructor, get Autofac to return the concrete instance of the parameter and then instantiate the object, while at the same time still allowing the other, constructorless classes be instantiated?

Comment: "has no constructors" - well, they have default constructor (or maybe explicit parameterless constructors) - else this oil don't work. But basically: you need to query the constructors and see what is there

Comment: I knew someone would say this.  I know this.

Comment: @SachinKainth, you know how to get the appropriate constructor?  Then invoke it.

Comment: No, I meant that I know that all objects have a default constructor.

Comment: Is `T` a derivative of an interface or is it an actual interface? As far as I remember, a default constructor isn't generated for an interface, which would explain why you're getting that specific error.

Comment: T is the derivative of an interface.

Comment: @SachinKainth why not use `Autofac` instead of `Activator`, e.g. `autofac.Resolve(Type.GetType(cls))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you define a constructor in your code, the compiler will no longer generate the default - parameterless - constructor for you. This usually isn't that big of a problem, unless you're using `Lazy<T>` or in your case: `Activator.CreateInstance`, which will always use the default, parameterless constructor.

The "cleanest" way of forcing classes that are passed into this method to have a parameterless constructor is using the `new()` constraint to your method:

`public T SomeMethod<T>(Assembly asm, T type) where T : new()`

This will tell the compiler that whatever calls this function is **required** to have a parameterless constructor, and if it doesnt, it won't compile.

The somewhat dirtier way is just to declare a parameterless constructor in the type that's currently giving you issues, but that's a bandaid; it's not actually resolving the problem.

*Note: If you're using any other sort of constraint on your method, the `new()` constraint must always be the last one.*

Comment: Problem is that the type passed in is an interface and they can't have constructors, plus the whole point is that this should work for the classes with the default constructor and the constructor with a parameter.  +1 for effort but this does not work.

Comment: But you're not creating instances of your interface, you're creating instances of classes that implement the interface right? It'd work if you use actual types that implement the interface as long as they define both the constructor that declare both the constructor that does take parameters and the parameterless one.